# Eating cookie dough

Tags: eggs, cookies, raw

How can I eat cookie dough safely? I want to make cookie dough ice-cream like the Ben and Jerry's range, however I don't want salmonella.

1. How do Ben and Jerry's sell make theirs, assuming they don't sell it raw?
2. Is it possible to cook the egg or dough without changing the raw uncooked feel of cookie dough?
3. Is there a good substitute? (I have tried banana)

Comment: Related question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/62235/is-eating-cookie-dough-without-egg-safe

Answer (score 16):

To make cookie dough to eat raw you have a couple of choices:

- Leave the eggs out
- Use pasteurized eggs

I'm not sure how Ben and Jerry's make theirs, but I suspect it is by pasteurizing at some point in the manufacturing process. Leaving the egg(s) out is the simplest method and doesn't make a big difference in the final product (when you are not going to bake the dough). If you want to use pasteurized eggs, they are generally available in supermarkets or you can do it yourself at home. Here is one example of instructions I found through searching the web - [How to Pasteurize Eggs](http://www.wikihow.com/Pasteurize-Eggs)

Comment: Stovetop pasteurization like that will definitely work... but it sounds like a huge pain to hold the temperature there. Doesn't take too much extra heat to start cooking the eggs. If you do have a sous vide circulator, it makes it a *lot* easier.

Comment: @Jefromi "*generally available in supermarkets*" comes right before how to do it yourself, and will take the huge pain out of it, converting that to a small pain in the wallet.

Comment: For large scale commercial applications irradiation is another feasible technique. But I don't recommend you scavenging radioactive materials form your smoke detector to make cookie dough :)

Comment: There's also the option of deep freezing the dough for a couple of weeks to kill all the bugs, but you need a special freezer for that.

Comment: Pasteurization probalby isn't sufficient -- as long as the egg is still liquid it still has the capacity for salmonella.  The fact is there is no need whatsoever for eggs in a raw cooke-dough recipe, it is there to change texture when cooking.   So just adapt to moisture ratio.

Comment: As I recently learned and mention at https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/117077/45194 , eggs are not the only problem. The flour is a risk, too.

Answer (score 1):

Dry powdered eggs is a good option. Not the freeze dried scrambled style eggs you might take on a camping trip into the back country. I see the product commonly in the baking aisle of the grocers, near the yeasts and baking powder.